# Unit tests in Symfony 2.8 running hundreds of times slower than they should

Tags: performance, unit-testing, phpunit, symfony-2.8, php-5.5

I'm adding unit tests to an old Symfony 2.8 production codebase that never had them before so I can upgrade Symfony to a maintained version. We will also upgrade PHP since we're currently running PHP 5.5 which is also no longer maintained, but Symfony 2.8 throws far too many errors if it's run under PHP 7.3.

Although I'm able to get the unit tests running under both PHPUnit and Codeception (powered by  PHPUnit), they run incredibly slowly.

For example:

#### SimpleTest.php

```
<?php
class SimpleTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
  public function testShouldDoNothing() {
    $this->assertTrue(true);
  }
}
```

#### phpunit.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php" colors="true">
    <php>
        <server name="KERNEL_DIR" value="app/"/>
    </php>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Application Test Suite">
            <directory>tests/unit</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

#### PHPUnit run output

```
PHPUnit 4.8.36 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Runtime:        PHP 5.5.9 with Xdebug 2.5.5

.

Time: 19.52 seconds, Memory: 6.00MB

OK (1 test, 1 assertion)
```

#### codeception.yml

```
paths:
    tests: tests
    output: tests/_output
    data: tests/_data
    support: tests/_support
    envs: tests/_envs
actor_suffix: Tester
extensions:
    enabled:
        - Codeception\Extension\RunFailed
coverage:
    enabled: true
    include:
        - src/*
    low_limit: 50
    high_limit: 100
```

#### Codeception run output

```
Codeception PHP Testing Framework v2.3.9
Powered by PHPUnit 4.8.36 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Unit Tests (1) --------------------------------------------------
Testing unit
+ SimpleTest: Should do nothing (0.29s)
-----------------------------------------------------------------

Time: 30.96 seconds, Memory: 23.25MB

OK (1 test, 1 assertion)
```

This test should consistently run in `0.00s`, and the total time should be less than `5 seconds`, not `20 seconds` or more.

How can I speed up unit testing under Symfony 2.8 in PHP 5.5?

---

I've tracked down the problem to running PHP 5.5, which is currently a requirement. I've created a vanilla Symfony 2.8 installation with PHP 5.5 and with no code the tests are still impractically slow. When I switch to PHP 7.3, the tests are as fast as I've expected them to be in the past, however, our project does not yet run under PHP 7.3 as it causes fatal errors.

```
D:\server\Apache24\htdocs\symfony-2.8>php55 vendor\codeception\codeception\codecept run unit
Codeception PHP Testing Framework v2.3.9
Powered by PHPUnit 4.8.36 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Unit Tests (1) --------------------------------------------------
+ SimpleTest: Should do nothing (0.20s)
-----------------------------------------------------------------

Time: 21.84 seconds, Memory: 14.50MB

OK (1 test, 1 assertion)

D:\server\Apache24\htdocs\symfony-2.8>php73 vendor\codeception\codeception\codecept run unit
Codeception PHP Testing Framework v2.3.9
Powered by PHPUnit 4.8.36 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Unit Tests (1) --------------------------------------------------
+ SimpleTest: Should do nothing (0.00s)
-----------------------------------------------------------------

Time: 264 ms, Memory: 10.00MB

OK (1 test, 1 assertion)
```

Comment: Have you tried to disable the coverage? Whenever I run tests with coverage it adds a solid 20 seconds to the total time. That might be slowing this single test down a lot as well.

Comment: @DirkScholten Both are run without coverage. Coverage turns a 6 minute run into an hour run.